# proftpd limit to 2 subdirectories

Tags: debian, proftpd

User can access */var* on FTP but I want to limit to only two subfolders: */var/www* and */var/server*.

I tried creating two directory rules for the two subfolders and setting DefaultRoot to */var*, but the user can still view and access the others subfolders.

The rules I created:

```
<Directory /var/www>
  <Limit ALL>
    AllowUser ftpuser
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/server>
  <Limit ALL>
    AllowUser ftpuser
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
</Directory>

DefaultRoot /var
```

Tried creating a rule in directory /var/ to deny all, but then I can't access anything.

Comment: Please post a relevant configuration directives (i.e. content of `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`, ...)

Comment: @MilošĐakonović done